# Unsetting Facebook Application Restrictions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing locking down my facebook app by location using the restrictions property as mentioned on [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) page and demonstrated on [this](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574/) page.

I was able to set the restriction just fine by calling this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>?restrictions={"location":"US"}&method=post&access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I cannot find a way to remove the restriction, however, calling this does not work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>?restrictions={"location":"US"}&method=delete&access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, its simpler than I would have thought. You just have to do set the location to be an empty string:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<APP_ID>?restrictions={"location":""}&method=post&access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```